# C++: Convert 3D environment to 2D screen coordinates

Tags: 3d, 2d, screen, converters

This is some kind of a math question, but since I need to do the math in C++ I chose StackOverflow.
Lets say I have the following variables:
`cameraX`, `cameraY`, `cameraZ`, `cameraAngleVertical`, `cameraAngleHorizontal`.
Using these vriables, how can I calculate the 2D-screen-coordinate of a 3D-environment-coordinate?

Comment: That's what ray-tracing engines are for ...

Comment: What do the variables (the angle ones) mean? And that's not enough information for computing the view & projection matrices (<= search hints ;-) ). Basically, you need camera position, camera view vector, field of view.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Although you are doing the calculations in C++, it's not a C++ related question, since the math is completely independet of the language you implement it in.

Comment: The field of view would probably be the screen width*height. About the camera view vector, what information owuld this vector carry?